# How do I create a new Group after installing OG?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I downloaded the Organic Groups module for my drupal 7 account. I moved it to my sites/all directory and was able to see it in the Drupal settings where I checked off all of the Organic Groups sections and the Locale. However when I go to Create/Add Content I don't see the option to create a Group. Did I do something wrong? Has anyone else seen this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in the content type. Go to a content type you would like to use as a group and you will see a fieldset Organic groups

Also check your permissions, you will have permissions for creating the content types and for administering og

Comment: thx for the answer. You helped me alot!